calculate per site and sample missingness using tetraploid genotype calls in vcf
I have a vcf file with tetraploid genotype calls, and would like to filter snps and samples based on the proportion of missing genotype calls for each snp and sample. I haven't been able to achieve this for tetraploid calls with any of the tools I've  tried (vcftools, bcftools, plink). Bcftools should be able to do this but is not calculating the proportion of missing sites correctly. The issue seems to be that there are two types of missing calls in the vcf file: one with no information .:.:.:.:.:.:. that is correctly counted as missing and another indicating a missing genotype ./././. followed by coverage information, which isn't counted as missing. I've written a custom script that counts the occurances of  ./././.  and updates the 'NS' field for each snp, so that  can be used to calculate site missingness. However, I haven't been able to calculate sample missingness.
I've included an example of a snp I've been testing troubleshooting with, since it has a lot of missing genotypes.
Scaffold_1      43629806        .       CTCTC   CTCTG   16620.9 .       AB=0.196078;ABP=43.9277;AC=25;AF=0.0932836;AN=268;AO=54;CIGAR=4M1X;DP=728;DPB=728;DPRA=0.996137;EPP=80.8616;EPPR=18.2106;GTI=8;LEN=1;MEANALT=1.55556;MQM=57.7593;MQMR=60;NS=67;NUMALT=2;ODDS=0.391415;PAIRED=1;PAIREDR=1;PAO=0;PQA=0;PQR=0;PRO=0;QA=1948;QR=259;RO=7;RPL=5;RPP=80.8616;RPPR=18.2106;RPR=49;RUN=1;SAF=54;SAP=120.27;SAR=0;SRF=7;SRP=18.2106;SRR=0;TYPE=snp;technology.illumina=1      GT:DP:AD:RO:QR:AO:QA ./././.:15:0,15,0:0:0:0:0       ./././.:9:0,9,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:4:0,4,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:5:0,5,0:0:0:0:0 .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:14:0,14,0:0:0:0:0       ./././.:7:0,7,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:11:0,11,0:0:0:0:0       ./././1:23:0,19,3:0:0:3:111  ./././.:12:0,12,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:23:0,23,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:5:0,5,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:10:0,10,0:0:0:0:0       ./././.:21:0,21,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:10:0,10,0:0:0:0:0   .:.:.:.:.:.:.    ./././.:34:0,34,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:17:0,17,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:10:0,10,0:0:0:0:0       ./././.:22:0,22,0:0:0:0:0       ./././.:20:0,20,0:0:0:0:0       ./././.:1:0,1,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:1:0,1,0:0:0:0:0      ./././.:16:0,15,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:18:0,18,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././1:4:0,3,1:0:0:1:37        ./././.:8:0,8,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:1:0,1,0:0:0:0:0      ./././.:15:0,15,0:0:0:0:0       ./././.:11:0,11,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:9:0,9,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:7:0,7,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:12:0,12,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   1/1/1/1:8:0,0,8:0:0:8:296    ./././.:2:0,2,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:4:0,4,0:0:0:0:0 ././1/1:11:0,6,5:0:0:5:185      ./././.:1:0,1,0:0:0:0:0 .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:17:0,17,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:13:0,13,0:0:0:0:0    ./././.:15:0,15,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:14:0,14,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././0:29:7,22,0:7:259:0:0     .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:8:0,8,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:12:0,12,0:0:0:0:0       ./././.:1:0,1,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:3:0,3,0:0:0:0:0      ./././.:15:0,15,0:0:0:0:0       ./././.:9:0,9,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:8:0,8,0:0:0:0:0 .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:8:0,8,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:9:0,9,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:8:0,8,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:6:0,6,0:0:0:0:0 1/1/1/1:7:0,0,7:0:0:7:259    ./././.:14:0,14,0:0:0:0:0       .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:1:0,1,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:6:0,6,0:0:0:0:0 .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././.:2:0,2,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:8:0,8,0:0:0:0:0 1/1/1/1:13:0,0,13:0:0:13:443    .:.:.:.:.:.:.   ./././1:13:0,12,1:0:0:1:37   ./././.:19:0,19,0:0:0:0:0       1/1/1/1:1:0,0,1:0:0:1:37        ./././.:9:0,9,0:0:0:0:0 .:.:.:.:.:.:.   .:.:.:.:.:.:.   1/1/1/1:15:0,0,15:0:0:15:543    ./././.:29:0,29,0:0:0:0:0       ./././.:4:0,4,0:0:0:0:0 ./././.:11:0,11,0:0:0:0:0

I've confirmed that the 'NS' field only counts .:.:.:.:.:.:. as missing, and not genotype calls of ./././. With the help of GPT I've written a custom script  to update the 'NS' field based on the number of .:.:.:.:.:.:. occurrences for each snp (in this example NS is 10 after that is ran, script below).
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS}
    !/^#/ {  # Only process non-header lines
        missing = 0
        for (i = 10; i <= NF; i++) {
            # Check if the genotype column starts with "./././."
            if (substr($i, 1, 7) == "./././.") {
                missing++
            }
        }

        # Split INFO field into key-value pairs
        split($8, info_array, ";")
        for (j in info_array) {
            # Split each info field on "=" and check for NS key
            split(info_array[j], kv, "=")
            if (kv[1] == "NS") {
                # Adjust the NS value based on missing genotype count
                kv[2] -= missing
                info_array[j] = kv[1] "=" kv[2]  # Reconstruct NS key-value pair
                break
            }
        }

        # Reassemble INFO field from the modified info_array
        $8 = info_array[1]
        for (j=2; j <= length(info_array); j++) {
            $8 = $8 ";" info_array[j]
        }

        # Reconstruct and print the entire line with updated INFO
        print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10
        for (k = 11; k <= NF; k++) {
            printf("%s%s", OFS, $k)
        }
        printf("\n")  # Print newline at the end of the record
    }
    /^#/ {print}  # Print header lines as they are
' freebayes_midwest_lib1A-2B_snp_call_QUAL20_MINDP5.vcf > freebayes_midwest_lib1A-2B_snp_call_QUAL20_MINDP5_corrected_NS.vcf

I haven't yet been able to correctly count per sample missingness with a similar approach- does anyone have ideas or  suggestions  for  how to do this? Are there tools that would be able to achieve this that I'm not aware of? Thanks in advance for any help!

First, I updated the NS fields based on any partial or complete missed calls that were not reflected in the NS field already, which had to start with ./ (./././. or ././0/0 or ./1/1/1, etc).
awk -F'\t' '
    BEGIN { OFS=FS; }
    !/^#/ {
        missing = 0;
        for (i = 10; i <= NF; i++) {
            if ($i ~ /^\.\//) {
                missing++;
            }
        }
        if (missing > 0) {
            # Split INFO field into key-value pairs
            nsplit = split($8, info_array, ";")
            # Iterate through the INFO fields and update NS if found
            for (j = 1; j <= nsplit; j++) {
                split(info_array[j], kv, "=");
                if (kv[1] == "NS") {
                    kv[2] -= missing;
                    info_array[j] = kv[1] "=" kv[2];
                    break;
                }
            }
            # Reassemble the INFO field from the modified info_array
            $8 = info_array[1];
            for (j = 2; j <= nsplit; j++) {
                $8 = $8 ";" info_array[j];
            }
        }
        print $0;
    }
    /^#/ { print $0; }
' freebayes_midwest_lib1A-2B_snp_call_QUAL20_MINDP5.vcf > freebayes_midwest_lib1A-2B_snp_call_QUAL20_MINDP5_corrected_NS.vcf

Then I printed to terminal the proportions of sites with >90% of calls and samples with > 25% of calls. This counted any occurrence of .:.:.:.:.:.:. or any call starting with ./ as missing.
INPUT_VCF="freebayes_midwest_lib1A-2B_snp_call_QUAL20_MINDP5_corrected_NS.vcf"
    awk -v smiss_threshold=0.90 -v imiss_threshold=0.25 '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = "\t";
        high_quality_sites = 0;
        total_sites = 0; 
        total_samples_above_threshold = 0;
    
        for (i = 1; i <= 96; i++) {
            sample_nonmissing[i] = 0;
            sample_sites[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    /^#CHROM/ {
        print;
        next;
    }
    !/^#/ {
        site_nonmissing = 0;
        for (i = 10; i <= NF; i++) {
            # Adjusted condition to check for both fully and partially missing genotypes
            if ($i != "./././." && $i != ".:.:.:.:.:.:." && !match($i, /\./)) {
                sample_nonmissing[i-9]++;
                site_nonmissing++;
            }
            sample_sites[i-9]++;
        }
        
        if ((site_nonmissing / 96) >= smiss_threshold) {
            high_quality_sites++;
        }
        total_sites++;
    }
    END {
        for (i = 1; i <= 96; i++) {
            sample_proportion = sample_nonmissing[i] / sample_sites[i];
            if (sample_proportion >= imiss_threshold) {
                total_samples_above_threshold++;
            }
            print "Sample " i ": non-missing proportion=" sample_proportion;
        }
        
        print "Total number of high-quality sites: " high_quality_sites "/" total_sites " (" high_quality_sites*100/total_sites "%)";
        print "Total number of samples above the threshold: " total_samples_above_threshold "/96 (" total_samples_above_threshold*100/96 "%)";
    }
    ' "$INPUT_VCF"
    #Total number of high-quality sites: 1402/1694 (82.7627%)
    #Total number of samples above the threshold:    96      out of  96      (100%)

I Then could filter by site missingness,  which I ran by executing the below script as
./filter_ns.awk freebayes_midwest_lib1A-2B_snp_call_QUAL20_MINDP5_corrected_NS.vcf > freebayes_midwest_lib1A-2B_snp_call_QUAL20_MINDP5_corrected_NS_FMISS0.1.vcf

Script:
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = "\t";
    OFS = FS;
    required_ns = 87;  # At least 87 non-missing samples required (more than 90% of 96)
}

# Print header lines as they are
/^#/ {
    print;
    next;
}

# Process non-header lines
{
    info_field = $8;
    split(info_field, info_array, ";");
    for (i in info_array) {
        split(info_array[i], kv, "=");
        if (kv[1] == "NS") {
            ns_value = kv[2];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (ns_value >= required_ns) {
        print;
    }
}
 

